# How to start window.onload "onload"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a website with unchanged header and footer. The main div is changed when one clicks the sites. Here is the code:

```
<p id="item1">Item 1</p>
...
<script>
  $("#item").click(function(){$("#main").load("item1.html");});
</script>
```

In item1.html:

```
<div id="sth"></div>
...
<script>
  window.onload = function() {document.getElementById("sth").style.width = ...
</script>
```

Item1.html works fine when I open it separately (url = mywebsite.com/item1.html). But when I start it with the script above (index.html), the window.onload function don't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have anything else loading with window? Only one script can load and the others that follow will be ignored.

Comment: Edit: I meant the other way around which is the last function called on window load will be the only one fired.

Comment: Thanks. Only this script is loaded with window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) success callback function as mentioned below

```
$("#item").click(function(){
   $("#main").load("item1.html", function(){
          // your logics here 
         document.getElementById("sth").style.width =...
    });
});
```

You can understand the use of [window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)